# preview multiple thumbnails of images

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, shell

I have this piece of `sh` code which takes one argument at a time:

```
#!/bin/sh
    
clear
    
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo -n "There are no arguments. Please try again with arguments."
    echo
    exit
elif [ ! -f "$*" ]
    then
        echo -n "The image file '$*' doesn't exist!"
        echo
        exit
else
    display -size 40x50 $*
fi
```

How would I be able to make it print out up to 5 arguments therefore show 5 thumbnails at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `else` statement use a `for` loop to go over the input:

```
for i in $*; do
    if [ ! -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "invalid file $i"
    else
        display -size 40x50 $i &
    fi
done
```

The trick is to use `&` which makes the current task go to the background.

Comment: Having a semicolon after the ampersand will produce an error.

Comment: yeah i know i found out the error...just remove the semicolon and it would work...

Comment: you should use `"$@"` instead of `$*`